# How to chose the right version of SuperSU.zip for flashing?

Tags: rooting, twrp, asus-zenfone-2, supersu

I flashed TWRP on my ZE551ML (Z00A-WW-2.20.40.198) and wanted to root a clean stock rom. I have successfully done so before on the same device by installing `BETA-SuperSU-v2.67-20160121175247.zip` downloaded from the official Chainfire site. I thought it would be better to have the newest version, so this time I tried to install `SR1-SuperSU-v2.79-SR1-20161221223537.zip` from the same source. However, after installing that file, the phone stayed in a bootloop for around 10 minutes.

1. Is it normal for it to take that long, or does that mean that the second file is incompatible with my phone?
2. Did I chose the wrong file, and should I have installed `BETA-SuperSU-v2.67-20160121175247.zip` instead?
3. Which zip should I install?

I have uninstalled again, and my phone boots. What I am asking about here is which file to install.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a systemless thing... In TWRP go to terminal and enter "echo SYSTEMLESS=true>>/data/.supersu" press enter and reflash SuperSU, and reboot.